# how to save position of x and y coordinate

Tags: android, coordinates, joystick

I have a `joystick` that have an `x` and `y coordinates` and I want to move the `Imageview` to the `position` of the `x` and `y coordinates` but retaining its `position` and not going back to 0,0 again.I have already tried setting the `x` and `y coordinates` of the `imageview` by getting the `coordinates` of the `joystick` but the joystick is going back to `0,0` `everytime` I `untouch` the `screen`.

```
if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                        || move.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

                    attackImage.setX(arg1.getX());
                    attackImage.setY(arg1.getY());}
```

Comment: did you try this example https://github.com/erz05/JoyStick ???

Comment: i had tried this example sir [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Em4Qa09-y90)

Comment: thank you sir i will try that example @Javacoder